# BEM(CSS)を取り入れたサイトを教えて下さい

Tags: css

BEMの勉強のために参考にしたいので、BEMを使ったサイトをおしえてください。

海外のサイトでも大丈夫です。

Answer (score 3):

[Material Design Lite](https://getmdl.io/index.html)はBEMに沿ったクラス名を使用しています。